# Isn't disowning someone a form of being faithless?

Tags: 2-timothy

```
11 Here is a trustworthy saying:

If we died with him,
    we will also live with him;
12 if we endure,
    we will also reign with him.
If we disown him,
    he will also disown us;
13 if we are faithless,
    he remains faithful,
    for he cannot disown himself.
```

In particular, 12b and 13 confuse me. Isn't disowning someone a form of being faithless? If I disown God, am I not also being faithless? Therefore the end seems contradictory to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Hermeneutics.SE!

Answer (score 3):

In this case the answer is a bit more clear if you read from a different translation:

> If we deny Him, He also will deny us;
>
> If we are faithless, He remains faithful, for He cannot deny Himself.
>
> [*-2 Timothy 2:12-13, NASB*](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%202:12-13&version=NASB)

---

***Faith*** means "trust ***in God***".  This is the source of the confusion.  In modern English, when we say "faith", it can mean "believing" in *anything*, but in the New Testament, this word is only used to describe a response ***to God***.  *(See Vine's Dictionary)*

***Faithful*** is the verbal adjective of ***faith***.  (*πιστὸς* vs. *πίστις*).  This word essentially means "having faith in God".

***Faithless*** is equivalent to "not having faith in God", or "denying God", and is **not** equivalent to "denying man".

---

So, the passage is essentially saying:

```
If man denies God, God will deny man;
If man denies God, God will not deny God, for God cannot deny Himself.
```